# How to prevent my NextJS + Supabase app from flashing Login page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I'm using Supabase with NextJS to make a dashboard and I'm facing this kind of trouble:

Every time a user get into the application, the `Login` page flash for 1 second and then authenticate the user and redirect to a content page.

Video showing the problem:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48700146/214397435-a0bb3623-2097-4fdf-80c8-982a1d77a0a2.mp4

As you can see, I'm not using Supabase login component.

**Layout.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Layout({ children }: Props) {
  const supabaseSession = useSession();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>LysiMed</title>
      </Head>
      {supabaseSession ? (
        <Flex className={inter.className}>
          <Menu />
          <Box flex={1}>{children}</Box>
        </Flex>
      ) : (
        <Login />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

**_app.tsx**

```
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{ initialSession: Session }>) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [supabase] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const start = () => {
      setLoading(true);
    };
    const end = () => {
      setLoading(false);
    };
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", start);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", end);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", end);
    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", start);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", end);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeError", end);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <ChakraProvider>
        {loading ? (
          <Loading>
            <Spinner size="xl" color="green.400" />
          </Loading>
        ) : (
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        )}
      </ChakraProvider>
    </SessionContextProvider>
  );
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "next": "13.0.7",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.5.2",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-react": "^0.3.1",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.2.3",
}
```

I think that this kind of problem is happening because `useSession()` is asynchronous and it returns `null` while Supabase client checks user credentials.

Whats the best way to solve this?

Comment: `useSession()` most likely returns a `isLoading` or similar property, and you can use it to optionally render a loading component: `isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Layout />`

Comment: @yqlim no, it doesnt

Comment: If its the same as next-auth is is returning undefined first. After checking if the user is logged in it goes to null or the Session object.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

Instead of using the hook `useSession()` - witch returns `Session | null` - it's better to use `useSessionContext()` that returns this interface:

```
{
      isLoading: boolean;
      session: null | Session;
      error: null | AuthError;
      supabaseClient: SupabaseClient;
}
```

source: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/blob/main/packages/react/src/components/SessionContext.tsx